# gdb cannot work under mac os after creating a certificate and codesign

Tags: macos, gdb

I have been trying to install and use gdb in mac os. 
I first homebrew gdb and create a certificate from the keychain
i followed the steps online.
I also kill the taskgated and try to codesign in the terminal.
Everything seems to work, but when I tried to use gdb, I still get

```
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 730: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

I also tried to run

```
sudo gdb <name>
```

I get the information like this

```
Starting program: /Users/leon/Desktop/os4/kitty -o o.txt in.txt
[New Thread 0x1303 of process 744]
[New Thread 0x1103 of process 744]
During startup program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: We may need to examine the steps you took to authorize gdb

Comment: 1.create a new certificate in the keychian app.

Comment: 2.chose code signing.3.choose 'let me override'. 4.continue to skip all the steps until specify the location. 5. choose login. 6.drag the certificate to the system. 6.restart the computer 7. in the terminal, type codesign.

Comment: Ok.  `codesign` all by itself doesn’t do anything.  You must specify what to code sign and which cert to use.

Answer (score 0):

`codesign` all by itself doesn’t do anything. You must specify what to sign and which cert to use.

The syntax is like:
`codesign -fs nameofcertificate /path/to/binaryexecutable`

For example if you named the certificate `gdbc` and you are trying to sign `/usr/local/bin/gdb` then you would issue the following command:

`codesign -fs gdbc /usr/local/bin/gdb`

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply! I tried to use the command you offered before.

Comment: I got this prompt: /usr/local/bin/gdb: replacing existing signature. And i tried to use gdb again, but i still got the information: Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 12504: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))